# Rename columns name that change over time with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file to process but the columns name and the order change over time.
I want to rename the columns name in a manner that i will able to work even that they are a change in the file.

for exp: sometimes is

**exp 1:**

```
postcode brand
abde     exp1
enter code here
```

**exp 2**

```
PostCode brands
abdx     exp2
```

**exp 3**

```
brands postcode
abde     exp1
```

The expcted output

```
PostCode brand
abde     exp1
```

NB: i cannot use index because the order changes over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to this question, everything depends on the variability of your header…

Let's imagine that case: order and plural are the only variations. You could `map` a cleaning function to your column names, and sort the columns:

```
def clean_name(s):
    # make lowercase
    s = s.lower()
    # remove trailing 's'
    s = s.rstrip('s')
    return s

df.columns = df.columns.map(clean_name)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Example input:

```
  PostCode brands
0     abde   exp1
```

output:

```
  brand postcode
0  exp1     abde
```

Answer (score 1):

You could standardize the column names for your DataFrame as follows:

```
>>> df.rename(columns={c: "PostCode" if "postcode" in c.lower() else "Brand" for c in df.columns})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a column mapper dictionary that you can add to over time:

```
col_map = {
  "postcode": "PostCode",
  "brands": "brand",
}

col_order = ["PostCode", "brand"]

renamed_df = df.columns.map(lambda x: col_map.get(x, x)) # <- Renames the cols to the dict values
ouput = renamed_df.reindex(columns=col_order ) # <- reorders the cols based on the config list
```

**NOTE**
`col_map.get(x, x)` will fallback to the provided col if it is new, ie. "Brands"

If instead you want it to error so you can easily identify the issue and update the `col_map` you could use `df.columns.map(col_map)`